# How to convert ConfigValue to List[ConfigObject] in typesafeconfig

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I am new to Scala and to typesafeconfig. I have the following issue - 
I have a configuration like this -

```
a = [
      {
        b1 = [
          { 
            c1 = 3, 
            c2 = 4
          }, {
            c1 = 3, 
            c2 = 21
          }
        ]
      }, {
        b2 = [
          {
            c1 = 10, 
            c2 = 56
          }, 
          # ...many more elements
        ]
      }
      # .
      # .
      # .many more elements
    ]
```

I have been able to put the above in a Map[String, ConfigValue] using the following code -

```
val list : Iterable[ConfigObject] = config.getObjectList(PathTo 'a').asScala

val pairs = for {
  item: ConfigObject <- list
  entry : Entry[String, Config] <- item.entrySet().asScala
  key = entry.getKey
  value = entry.getValue.atKey(key)
 } yield (key, value)

pairs.toMap
```

In this Map I am getting keys as b1, b2, etc. - which is fine but the problem is that I am getting values as ConfigValue (and I not finding a good way to capture values List[ConfigObject] or something better). So, for example, at runtime I can see my that the value corresponding to key b1 has two entries - {c1=3, c2=4} and {c1=3, c2=21} but I am unable to traverse these two one by one and get to c1 and c2.

So, my question to folks with a bit of experience in TypeSafeConfig and Scala is - is there a better way I can make my Map so that I can traverse the values in b1, b2, etc. with ease or is there a good way to convert my current value which is a ConfigValue to something better that's iterable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `toMap` is found on a collection of type `Collection[(K, V)]` (collections of 2-tuples), and it returns a `Map[K, V]`.  Duplicate keys are **lost**.  Instead of calling `pairs.toMap`, you need to group each value by its key, first:

```
pairs.groupBy(_._1)         // produces a Map[String, Array[(String, ConfigValue)]
  .mapValues(_.map(_._1))   // produces a Map[String, Array[ConfigValue]
```

This should give you the ability to iterate through the configurations as you need.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I really don't like the interfaces on Java typesafe config objects. This looks like a good library for adding more scala friendly interfaces to the java objects:

https://github.com/iheartradio/ficus

To parse your values, all the code required would be:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
  """
    |a = [
    |      {
    |        b1 = [
    |          {
    |            c1 = 3,
    |            c2 = 4
    |          }, {
    |            c1 = 3,
    |            c2 = 21
    |          }
    |        ]
    |      }, {
    |        b2 = [
    |          {
    |            c1 = 10,
    |            c2 = 56
    |          },
    |          # ...many more elements
    |        ]
    |      }
    |      # .
    |      # .
    |      # .many more elements
    |    ]
  """.stripMargin)

import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._

val myComplicatedStructure = config.as[List[Map[String, List[Map[String, Int]]]]]("a")
println(myComplicatedStructure)

// prints List(Map(b1 -> List(Map(c2 -> 4, c1 -> 3), Map(c2 -> 21, c1 -> 3))), Map(b2 -> List(Map(c2 -> 56, c1 -> 10))))
```

If you do not want to add another library, this will work as a one off parser in java:

```
  val myComplicatedStructureFromJava = config.getConfigList("a").asScala.toList.map{ relativeConfig =>

  relativeConfig.root().entrySet().asScala.map { entry =>

    val key = entry.getKey

    val configList2 = relativeConfig.getConfigList(key).asScala.toList

    key -> configList2.map{ relativeConfig2 =>

      relativeConfig2.root().entrySet().asScala.map{ entry2 =>

        val key2 = entry2.getKey

        key2 -> relativeConfig2.getInt(key2)

      }.toMap

    }
  }.toMap
}

println(myComplicatedStructureFromJava)

// prints List(Map(b1 -> List(Map(c2 -> 4, c1 -> 3), Map(c2 -> 21, c1 -> 3))), Map(b2 -> List(Map(c2 -> 56, c1 -> 10))))

// or, if you just want a List[Map[String, List[Config]]]

val myComplicatedStructureFromJava2: List[Map[String, List[Config]]] = config.getConfigList("a").asScala.toList.map{ relativeConfig =>

  relativeConfig.root().entrySet().asScala.map { entry =>

    val key = entry.getKey

    val configList2 = relativeConfig.getConfigList(key).asScala.toList

    key -> configList2
  }.toMap
}

println(myComplicatedStructureFromJava2)

// List(Map(b1 -> List(Config(SimpleConfigObject({"c1":3,"c2":4})), Config(SimpleConfigObject({"c1":3,"c2":21})))), Map(b2 -> List(Config(SimpleConfigObject({"c1":10,"c2":56})))))
```

Comment: I understand your point but I'd rather not include a library in the codebase which I am new at :)

Comment: Understandable. Just trying to wrap my head around the stupid java API. We'll see if I can write something useable. Is the final type that you're after `List[Map[String, List[Map[String, Int]]]]`?